# What does the exif ICC profile date mean?

Tags: exiftool

I am trying to determine when a photo was taken with a smart phone. It was sent to me, not taken from facebook. I've viewed the exif data but the only field that even references a date is the ICC profile date. What is this date? is this the date it was taken? if not, how can I view the date it was taken?

Answer (score 7):

It is the date and time the ICC Profile used by that image was first created.  For example, my scanner inserts the same profile date for each image from 2006, even though I didn't have the scanner until 2010.

If you don't see any other date in the metadata, then it just isn't there.  If it was a screenshot off of a phone and not the original image, for example, the metadata isn't going to be there.  If it was taken from a website, it might also not be there because many sites, like Facebook and Imgur, wipe metadata from the files.

What Exiftool calls the `ProfileDateTime` tag is the `dateTimeNumber` in the ICC spec.  If you check the [Exiftool tag listing](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Image-ExifTool/lib/Image/ExifTool/TagNames.pod#ICC_Profile-Header-Tags) on MetaCPan, you'll see that it's byte 24, which is the same as in the [ICC Profile Format Specification (page 21)](http://www.color.org/ICC_Minor_Revision_for_Web.pdf).  It is defined in the Specs as "Date and time this profile was first created".

Comment: Also, if it was sent via MMS, that's another possible point where exif data was lost.