# ICC version predates ICC datetime

Tags: metadata, color, icc-profile

On my photo, the ICC version is 2.0, however the ICC datetime is 2009.

Does this mean the device can not predate 2009, and that the photo must have been taken after 2009?

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not necessarily mean that. It is basically impossible to determine the provenance of a photo just from the photo's EXIF data. The ICC DateTime could have been manipulated by just about anything that handled the image file:

1. The DateTime was probably written by the recording device (camera).
2. It could have been modified by any software that handled the transport of the file, such as the camera manufacturer's proprietary photo viewing and management software when copying to a computer, or when uploading to a cloud service.
3. It could have been modified by any software used to manipulate or edit the image.

Also, ICC version 2 is *much* older than 2009, considering that according to the ICC itself, [version 4 was published in 2001](http://www.color.org/v4spec.xalter).

See also, [What does the exif ICC profile date mean?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/82495/)

Comment: Also, the date/time set in the camera at the time the image was captured could have been set to an incorrect value, so that an image taken in 2009 was dated as taken in 1979 because the camera's date was set to 1979 at the time the image was captured.